# Container with shared owner semantics

Tags: c++, containers, const-correctness

I am designing a container type with shared ownership semantics. It supports slicing, and consequently slices share ownership. One of my problems is that data sharing seems to interfere with const correctness, so I tried to pay attention to that, but I am not happy with the result.

The following is a vastly broken down version of my actual code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
class SharedMem
{
public:
    SharedMem(std::initializer_list<T> init)
    : m_mem(std::make_shared<std::vector<T>>(init.begin(), init.end()))
    , m_data(m_mem->data())
    , m_size(m_mem->size())
    { }

    SharedMem(SharedMem& other) = default;        // best-effort for copy-construction
    SharedMem(SharedMem const& other) = delete;   // disallow, would circumvent const-correctness

    SharedMem& operator = (SharedMem const& other) {
        std::copy(other.m_data, other.m_data + other.m_size, m_data);
        return *this;
    }

    std::size_t size() const
    { return m_size; }
    T& operator [] (std::size_t index)
    { return m_data[index]; }
    T const& operator [] (std::size_t index) const
    { return m_data[index]; }

    SharedMem slice(std::size_t first, std::size_t last) {
        SharedMem<T> ret(*this);
        ret.m_data += first;
        ret.m_size = last - first;
        return ret;
    }
    SharedMem const slice(std::size_t first, std::size_t last) const {
        SharedMem<T> ret(*this);
        ret.m_data += first;
        ret.m_size = last - first;
        return ret;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>> m_mem;   // shared underlying memory
    T* m_data;                               // start of slice
    std::size_t m_size;                      // size of slice
};
```

intended use:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    SharedMem<int> a { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    SharedMem<int> b { 8, 9 };
    SharedMem<int> c = a;   // shallow copy of a, data is shared
    a.slice(1, 3) = b;      // a = [0, 8, 9, 3, 4]
    c[4] = 6;               // a = [0, 8, 9, 3, 6]
}
```

Something tells me that I am on the wrong track. I see the following problems with my approach:

- It violates the rule of 3. I particularly dislike the need to disable the default copy constructor for the sake of fixing const-correctness. Otherwise one could create a non-const copy of a const object, and the latter could modify the former's elements.
- Copy construction and assignment implement very different operations. That's how I make `c = a` and `a.slice(1, 3) = b` do the right thing (actually very different things).

I am unsure whether I am running into trouble or not. Questions:

- Is this design okay or will it cause problems down the road? If so, which?
- If there is a serious flaw, how to fix/avoid it?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: The assignment seems broken, since it can write out of bounds of the contained range.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Sure. As I wrote, the code is simplified as much as possible. The actual code is >1000 lines long, with far more complex slicing, corresponding iterators, and other functionality. It also checks bounds :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate types to properly make this work in a const correct way. For very similar reasons that you discovered, `iterator` and `const_iterator` are different types for all standard library containers.

That said, I think it highly depends on your use case/code base and coding style whether I'd recommend going down that route (as it is a lot of overhead to protect coders from something that might never be an issue in your use case).

If you want to give it a try, one solution could look something like this:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<class T, bool Const>
    struct SharedInternalsT;

    template<class T>
    struct SharedInternalsT<T, true>
    {
        const T * m_data;
        std::size_t m_size;
    };

    template<class T>
    struct SharedInternalsT<T, false>
    {
        T * m_data;
        std::size_t m_size;
    };

    template<class T>
    using SharedInternals = SharedInternals<T, false>;

    template<class T>
    using ConstSharedInternals = SharedInternals<T, true>;
}

template<class T, bool Const>
class SharedMemT
{
public:

    using Traits = SharedMemTraits<T, Const>;
    using Ptr = typename Traits::Ptr;

    //now we can safely copy in a const correct way.
    SharedMemT(const SharedMemT & _other) :
    m_mem(_other.m_mem),
    m_internals(_other.m_internals)
    {

    }

private:

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>> m_mem;
    detail::SharedInternals<T, Const> m_internals;
};

template<class T>
using SharedMem = SharedMemT<T, false>;

template<class T>
using ConstSharedMem = SharedMemT<T, true>;
```

This would be the first step towards a solution. You'd most likely have to introduce more indirection in order to be able to properly construct ConstVersions from non-const versions (possibly by enabling/disabling certain templated copy constructors with `std::enable_if` etc.). As I said, I would only go down this route if you are building some sort of standard library compliant piece of code. If you are just building a small utility for your game or something along those lines, just ignore const correctness and don't waste your time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The analogy to const iterators is a very good point, and insightful indeed. The very need for two iterator types in contrast to a single (possibly const qualified) iterator type always appeared to be sub-optimal design to me. But I see the problem more clearly now.